# awaitMessages() does not respond to any messages on discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

this code is an example that responds to a slash command (/quiz) and sends a question from qiuz.json, then waits for a person to send an answer and compares it with the answer from quiz.json.
The bot sends a question, but doesn't record any messages I send in the channel at all, even if they are correct answers, and even if I remove the filter.
I also tried using createMessageCollector(), with the same issue happening.

My bot has the bot, messages.read, applications.commands, and the guilds.members.read scopes. I also enabled these privileged gateway intents, MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT, SERVER MEMBERS INTENT, and PRESENCE INTENT.

This is the code I'm having the issues with.

```
const quiz = require('./quiz.json');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('quiz')
        .setDescription('quiz time!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
        const filter = response => {
            return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
        };

        interaction.reply({ content: item.question, fetchReply: true })
            .then(() => {
                interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                    .then(collected => {
                        interaction.followUp(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`);
                    })
                    .catch(collected => {
                        interaction.followUp('Looks like nobody got the answer this time.');
                    });
            });
    },
};
```

I am using a command handler in index.js similar to the one mentioned in discord.js guide and it seems to work perfectly.
I'm using discord.js v14.1.2 and node.js v16.15.1

Comment: I don't know the discord api, but I notice an ill-advised mixture of async syntax and a failure to return a promise (or anything else) from the execute function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the issue was with my Intents and Partials, I didn't have the right ones required to read messages sent in chat.
I used a [template](https://github.com/umutxyp/discordJS-V14/blob/main/index.js) that includes all the GatewayIntentBits and Partials to test and the bot was working. (I also enabled them through the discord developer portal for my bot).